# Does it follow that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are the same sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two real sequences. Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a subsequence of $(b_n)$ and $(b_n)$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$. Does it follow that they are the same sequence?

I am not sure, I think if $ (a_n) $ and $ (b_n) $ are real sequences such that $ (a_n) $ is a subsequence of $ (b_n) $ and $ (b_n) $ is a subsequence of $ (a_n) $, then $ (a_n) $ and $ (b_n) $ are the same sequence if and only if they have exactly the same terms for each $ n $.

How can I prove or disprove the original statement?

Comment: Not sure what you want.  Consider $\{a_n\}=\{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\cdots\}$ and $\{b_n\}=\{1,0,1,0,1,0,\cdots \}$.  Is that a counterexample?  You certainly have that each sequence is a subsequence of the other, but there is no $n$ for which $a_n=b_n$.

Comment: With the usual definition of subsequence @lulu that's a perfect counterexample.

Comment: So what i wrote is correct? They are the same sequence iff they have exactly the same terms for each n?

Comment: It's your question, so you can ask it using whatever definition you want.  But absent a specific definition to the contrary, I'd certainly say that two sequence are the same if and only if $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: It is possible that two different real sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are such that one is a subsequence of the other, as show by @lulu in the comments. This is not true if you ask for *converging* sequences, however.

Comment: Just to be clear:  Say $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}=(-1)^n$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=(-1)^{n+1}$.  Then both sequences are $\{1,-1,1,-1, \cdots\}$ but under this definition they aren't the same since, for instance, $a_1\neq b_1$.  So other definitions are possible.  Worth noting that my example would still be a counterexample under this alternate definition.

Comment: Thanks, can i ask what does happen if they are converging subsequences?

Comment: Hint: in a convergent sequence, there is at most one value that occurs infinitely many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

It's not entirely clear what it means to say that two sequences coincide. The most natural thing is probably to normalize the indices, so that we are always running from $1$ to $\infty$ (or from $0$ to $\infty$ if you prefer, the point is to fix the indices).  Then we say that $\{a_n\}$ is the same as $\{b_n\}$ if and only if $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

With that definition, we can choose $$\{a_n\}=\{0,1,0,1,0,\cdots\}\quad \quad \& \quad \quad  \{b_n\}=\{1,0,1,0,1,\cdots\}$$

It is clear that each is a subsequence of the other and that they aren't the same sequence.